# Inserting every OTHER ROW from one table to another (VBA MS Access 2010)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working with manually created empty copy of table Products, which I named Products_Backup. What I want to do is to insert every other row from "Spices" category of products into this empty Products_Backup table, since there would be only 6 rows from total of 12 rows, that are in Products table under "Spices" category. The problem is that I don't know how to do that. I tried to use MOD operator for newly created ProductID, but my mentor told me that it is not a proper solution, since he could easily change this ProductID's value and I would get odd rows instead of even.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton0_Click()
    Dim db As Database, rst As Recordset
    Dim I As Integer, s, s1 As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    s = "SELECT Products.* FROM Products WHERE (((Products.CategoryNumber)=2));" ' This value is for Spices
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(s)
    I = 1
    While Not rst.EOF
      s1 = "INSERT INTO Products_Backup (ProductName, ProductID, CategoryNumber, OrderedUnits) VALUES ('" & rst!ProductName & "', " & I & " , '" & rst!CategoryNumber & "', '" & rst!OrderedUnits & "');"

      MsgBox ("Record inserted")

    db.Execute s1

      I = I + 1
      rst.MoveNext

       If I Mod 10 = 0 Then
         MsgBox ("Inserted  " & I & ".record")
       End If

    Wend

    rst.Close

    db.Close

    End Sub
```

So with this I can insert all 12 records into Products_Backup, with MsgBox telling me when 10th record was inserted.
But I still have no idea what to do to insert every other row into Products_Backup to get 6 records.

Comment: Why is `mod` not a proper solution? `If i mod 2 = 0` would be a great, well accepted solution. I don't understand why you're trying to `i mod 10` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vba
Dim booEveryOther as Boolean
booEveryOther = False

While Not rst.EOF
   If booEveryOther Then
      s1 = "INSERT INTO ...
   End If

   booEveryOther = Not booEveryOther
```

Just use a Boolean value that is set to `Not` itself with every new record.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should do it better

```
While Not rst.EOF
  s1 = " INSERT INTO Products_Backup (ProductName, ProductID, CategoryNumber, OrderedUnits) " & _
       " VALUES ('" & rst!ProductName & "', " & I & " , '" & rst!CategoryNumber & "', '" & rst!OrderedUnits & "');"
  db.Execute s1

  If I Mod 10 = 0 Then
     MsgBox ("Inserted  " & I & ".record")
  Else
     MsgBox ("Record inserted")
  End If

  I = I + 1
  rst.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Well, this is not actually an answer I was looking for, although it looks better. I still have no idea how to insert alternating rows into Products_Backup table.

Comment: This inserts every record and gives an alert every 10th.